# On a certain discrepancy measure between probability distributions on the symmetric group of permutation $\mathfrak S_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, symmetric-groups, discrete-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $\mathfrak S_n$ be the symmetric group of permutations on $n$ objects and let $P$ and $Q$ be a probability distributions on $\mathfrak S_n$ (i.e $P$ and $Q$ are points on the $n!$-simplex). For $1 \le i < j \le n$, let $p_{ij}$ be the probability that a random permutation $\sigma$ drawn from $P$ ranks $j$ ahead of $i$, i.e satisfies $\sigma(i) < \sigma(j)$. Consider the quantity $\Delta(P,Q) := \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n}|p_{ij}-q_{ij}|$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to reasonably upper-bound $\Delta(P,Q)$ in terms of some distance (e.g total variation) between $P$ and $Q$ ?

Comment: Not to hijack the comments of this question, but were you reading something that made you think of this? The idea of positioning distributions in space is really interesting and I'd love to read more about it

Comment: The question arises from a statistical learning-theoretic study of rankings (of say, user-based google search results or movies on Neflix). Think of $P$ and $Q$ as datasets of such rankings. Quantities of the form $\Delta (P,\hat{P}_N)$ appear in bounds on the rate of learning an optimal ranking from empirical samples from some unknown oracle distribution $P$. Here $\hat{P}_N$ is the empirical version of $P$ based on $N$ iid samples.

Comment: You may be aware of this: This quantity only depends on the marginal distributions of the pairs $(\sigma(i),\sigma(j))$, so if you have lots of such distributions on $\mathfrak S_n$ and want to compare them efficiently, you can first boil them down to these more manageable distributions.

Comment: I think the bound
$ \Delta(P,Q) \leq  2n^2 (TV(P,Q)) $ holds by a coupling argument

Comment: Hum, interesting. Indeed on second thought, coupling looks like the right trick to try out here. Thanks! Could you please explain the core of your idea in a sentence ?

Comment: @E-A I can get your bound via a direct computation. But the method employs a simplification which is so crude that the $n^2$ factor is presumably very sub-optimal.

Comment: Actually, the $n^2$ factor seems tight. Indeed if $P$ is a dirac and $Q$ is uniform, then $TV(P,Q) = (n!-1)/n! \sim 1$ and $\Delta(P,Q) = n(n-1)/4 = o(n^2)$.

Comment: I was just going to tell you to couple the P and Q together so that they pick the same sigma; only with probablity 1 - TV will they pick different sigmas in which case you can use the trivial n^2 bound on the indicators. (If you would like me to write it out I can) Good to know that n^2 bound is tight!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to obtain the bound speculated by E-A in the comments section, namely $\Delta(P,Q) \le Cn^2TV(P,Q)$. The main difference is that my method is very direct.

---

So, let $E_{ij} := \{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n \mid \sigma(i) < \sigma(j)\}$. This is the set of permutations which rank $j$ ahead of $i$. One can then rewrite
$p_{ij}  = \mathbb P_{\sigma \sim P}[\sigma \in E_{ij}] = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n}P(\sigma)1_{\sigma \in E_{ij}}$. Thus

$$
\begin{split}
\Delta(P,Q) &:= \sum_{i < j}|p_{ij}-q_{ij}| = \sum_{i < j}\left|\sum_{\sigma \in E_{ij}}(P(\sigma)-Q(\sigma))\right| \le \sum_{i < j}\sum_{\sigma \in E_{ij}}\left|P(\sigma)-Q(\sigma)\right|\
 \\
&\le \sum_{i < j}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n}\left|P(\sigma)-Q(\sigma)\right| = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n}\left|P(\sigma)-Q(\sigma)\right|\\
&= n(n-1)TV(P,Q) < n^2TV(P,Q),
\end{split}
$$
where the first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz.

---

## Edit 1: $n^2$ constant is actually tight!

Indeed if $P$ is a dirac and $Q$ is uniform, then $TV(P,Q) = (n!-1)/n! \sim 1$ and $\Delta(P,Q) = n(n-1)/4 = o(n^2)$.

Comment: Small note which neatens things a bit - since $TV(P,Q) = \sup_{A \subset \mathfrak S_n} P(A) - Q(A),$ it follows directly that $ |\sum_{\sigma \in E_{ij}} P(\sigma) -Q(\sigma)| = \max( P(E_{ij}) -Q(E_{ij}) , P(E_{ij}^c) - Q(E_{ij}^c) )\le TV(P,Q).$ This saves a factor of $2$, which is probably not important, but still. This is tight in the constants as well - take $P$ to be supported on the identity permutation, and $Q$ on the reverse $(n,n-1, \dots, 1)$. Then $TV(P,Q) = 1$, and for any $i < j,$ $P(E_{ij}) = 1, Q(E_{ij}) = 0,$ so $\Delta = \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Good catch. I was a bit lazy about the constants 1,2,1/2, etc.